# Can an L298N motor driver run a linear actuator?

Tags: arduino, actuator, motordriver

I am new in Arduino and electronics. I am trying to run the Sumret SRA6000 linear actuator with an L298N motor driver. Will it work? If not work, what motor driver can I use to synchronize both linear actuators? Is there any source for reference?

Specification SRA6000:

- Stroke: 250 mm
- Load capacity: 6000 N
- No-Load capacity: 5 mm/s
- Input voltage: 12 VDC

Below is the code that I use in the Arduino IDE:

```
#include <ActuatorsAndSensors.h>
#include <ActuatorsAndSensors.h>
#define IN1 2
#define IN2 3
#define ENA 4
//Instantiate the Linear Actuator
LinearActuator LinAct(IN1, IN2, ENA);
void setup() {

//Allows the actuator to recieve power
LinAct.turnOn();
}
void loop() {
int pwm = 255;
//Sends the actuator up at specified pwm (default value of 255 if not passed)
LinAct.goUp(pwm);
delay(5000);
//Stops linear actuator motion until a goUp() or goDown() but doesn't turn it off
LinAct.pause();
delay(5000);
//Sends the actuator down at specified pwm (default value of 255 if not passed)
LinAct.goDown(pwm);
delay(5000);
//Turns the linear actuator off, goUp() and goDown() will not work until turnOn() is called
LinAct.turnOff();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Sumret SRA6000](https://m.aliexpress.us/item/3256804224183614.html?gatewayAdapt=gloPc2usaMsite4itemAdapt) is rated 100 watts at 12 volts.  That mean it will draw over 8 amperes.

The [L298N](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf) is rated for a maximum of 3 amperes per channel.

On ratings alone, you can't drive the SRA6000 with an L298N.

If you know you will never need full power from the SRA6000, then you might squeak by - only to have the L298 burn out when you accidentally put a larger load on the actuator.

You need to look for an H-bridge IC or module rated for at least 9 amperes.  It should use MOSFETs instead of BJTs as the switching elements.  MOSFETs have lower loss when carrying high current - MOSFETs won't get as hot as BJTs.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials on how to run linear actuators with L298. But as JRE has already pointed out, L298 cannot give sufficient current to the particular actuator that you're using. So, I think you must use relays. You can choose a generic Songle relay module that will provide up to 10A.  Here is a tutorial on how to control a linear actuator with an Arduino via a relay module.

https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2017/11/how-to-use-an-arduino-with-linear-actuators.html